# Repeat block without until (or blank line) using algorithm2e

Tags: macros, algorithm2e, pseudocode

I'm trying to format a "repeat forever" block using `algorithm2e`. I've found the `\Repeat` command but this prints an `until` at the end of my block. I can hide the word until using:

```
\SetKwRepeat{Repeat}{repeat}{}
```

But then a blank line appears. I'm currently using the `noend` option so I'd like to completely remove the closing clause. How can I get rid of this blank line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\SetKwBlock`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKwBlock{Repeat}{repeat}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\Repeat{do these things}
\While{$i<n$}{a while loop\;
  \Repeat{do other things}
  this condition\;
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]